# React Native check context value on click test case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have following context

`Home.tsx`

```js
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null)

const Home = () => {
  const { width } = Dimensions.get("window")
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState({
    active: 0,
    heightOfScrollView: 0,
    profileWidth: width * 0.2,
    scrolledByTouchingProfile: false
  })
  
  const horizontalScrollRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>()
  const verticalScrollRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>()

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer} />
      <Header title="Contacts" />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
```

In component A, I have a button which changes in the context

```js
const onProfileTouched = (index: number) => {
  setTheme({ ...theme, active: index });
};
```

This leads to an image being active

```js
const ImageCircle = ({ active, uri }: Props) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={
        active
          ? { ...styles.parentView, ...styles.active }
          : { ...styles.parentView }
      }>
      <Image source={uri} width={30} height={30} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Now, I want to write a test case (I haven't written a test case before) that confirms that the state has actually changed or perhaps an active border is added to the image

I added a testId to my button which I used to fire an event

```js
it('changes active on profile clicked', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Home />);
  fireEvent.press(getByTestId('HScroll3.button'));
});
```

Now, I am unsure, how to grab the value of context or change in style so as I can confirm that indeed the component for which the button is pressed is active

I am using `import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react-native'` but open to change.

Answer (score 1):

With testing-library you want to check the visual output, not the internal state. This way your tests are much more valuable, because the end user doesn't care if you're using context, state or anything else, they care if the button has the "active" state. So if at some point you'll decide to change your mind and refactor theming completely, your test will still give you value and confidence.

I would suggest to install `@testing-library/jest-native`, you just have to add this `setupFilesAfterEnv": ["@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"]`
to your Jest config or import that `extend-expect` file in your test setup file.

Once you have it set up, you're ready to go.

I don't know what's in your `styles.active` style, but let's assume it's e.g. `{ borderColor: '#00ffff' }`.
Add a `testID` prop to the `View` in `ImageCircle` component, e.g. `testID="imageCircleView"`. Then to test if everything works as you'd expect, you just have to add this to your test:

```
expect(getByTestId('imageCircleView')).toHaveStyle({ borderColor: '#00ffff' });
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks so much. 
Marked this answered. :) 
Can you please see if you could help me with this as well?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338500/react-native-scroll-view-test-failing